# How to transition to root view controller without navigationController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application that transitions from the main launchVC to a register or login VC and then from there transitions into the main application view controller. Now I am not using the built in navigation that you can use with an iOS app instead I'm using my own buttons. So my question is how do I "pop back" to the launchVC. Image in application where you have logged in and when you tap "log out" all of the view controller get dismissed back to the launch view controller. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your launch view controller a delegate, passing it to the view controller that contains the logout button. Once the button is pressed, then that will notify the delegate (launch view controller) which can then dismiss all of the presented view controllers.

[Here](https://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/) is a tutorial on how to configure such a pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't what I was looking for. Great way to pass data backwards however I am not using a navigation controller at all. I want to get back to the main launch view controller without a navigation controller